# transition from viewcontroller to tab bar controller with a navigation controller at each tab error

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

Hi I added a prepare for segue code in order to transfer information, however I'm getting an error.

I have a tab bar controller. It has 4 tabs. Each tab has a navigation controller, and a VC as a root view controller.

from tab 1-->nav controller-->VC 1 I need to take a value to tab2-->nav controller --->VC1

(also is the segue connected to the nav controller at tab 2, or the root view at tab 2)
Thank you in advance

error:customizableViewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf19bd60
(but I am going to tab 2 (index 1))?
where is my error?

```
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ResultsSegue"])

        {
//the root VC at tab 2
            ResultsIndexViewController*controller=[[ResultsIndexViewController alloc]init];

            UITabBarController *tabController = [segue destinationViewController];
            controller = (ResultsIndexViewController*)[[tabController customizableViewControllers]objectAtIndex:1];//crashing here
            controller.resultsArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_matchedResultsArray];

        }
    }
```

Comment: also, do I need delegates for this?

Comment: Your error basically means, that `tabbarcontroller` is not a `UITabBarController`. Are sure, that `[segue destinationViewController]` returns a `UITabBarController`? Is that, how the segue is configured?

Comment: the segue goes to a navigation controller, should it be linked to tabbar controller?

Comment: O.k. - that explains the error: you think, that it's a tabbarcontroller, but it actually is an navigation controller. `customizableViewControllers` is a method for tabbarcontroller; nav controllers don't understand this. If it should be linked to a tabbar controller depends only on what you want to achieve. Nav controller is something completely different than a tab controller. Whatever; the code must reflect what is in your storyboard. Either both nav or both tabbar.

Comment: so I have a tabcontroller (bottom). It has four tabs. Each tab was created by having a UINav controller with a root view. the nav controllers were connected (dragged) to tab bar controller.

Comment: Again: if the segue leads to a nav controller, you'll have to write `UINavigationController *navController = [segue...` instead of `UITabBarController *tabController...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code

```
 [1]   UITabBarController *tabController = [segue destinationViewController];
 [2]    controller = (ResultsIndexViewController*)[[tabController customizableViewControllers]objectAtIndex:1];//crashing here
```

Is full of misconceptions.

In [1] you are assigning a destinationViewController (type `UIViewController`) to an object of type `UITabBarController`. This is compiler-legal (`UITabBarController` inherits from `UIViewController` so they are both of type `UIViewController`) but it doesn't reflect really what is going on. Your segue will be to the `UIViewController` or it's `UINavigationController`.

So in line [2] when you try to *use* your tabController as a tab bar controller, it crashes (because it isn't one).

You need to redesign your project... forget the Segue, and use the tab bar controller. Something like...

```
- (IBAction)moveToTab2:(id)sender {
    ResultsViewController* resultsVC = (ResultsViewController*)
                [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
    resultsVC.resultsArray=
                [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_matchedResultsArray];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:resultsVC;
}
```

Comment: One way to go would be to declare a property in your app delegate, set it from you first VC and get it in your second VC. Would that work for you? (Not the best, because it reeks of globals, but it does allow you to decouple your vcs...)

Comment: I guess, externs would work (not preferred) I think I need to use @protocols but I am having issues grasping that

Comment: To use a delegate, there is going to have to be some relationship between the VCs. I.e. one will have to be the delegate of the other. Unless you subclass the tabViewController and allow it to be the delegate of both. Or make the app delegate the delegate of both.

Comment: Sorry not thinking MVC... you should create a model object. I'll update my answer...

Comment: ok, delegates can only be used if on the same view nav controller?

Comment: See my update. Delegates require one of the objects to know about the other, so you might as well just set the data directly as you were attempting to do in the first place. Using a third-party entity to hold the data is just pushing the problem elsewhere (i.e. going global..). You'd only need a delegate if you need to return info back from the secondVC to the firstVC.